# How use map for key value when key is first?

Tags: laravel-5

What i am trying to do is get data from table (it is ajax request), sort and send to view. Want show in select box options. I have to change id with value to make JS sort by value.

Quick example

```
ModelVehicle::where('make_id', $request->make_id)->orderBy('name')->pluck('id', 'name');
```

and JS

```
$("#model_id").empty();
    $("#model_id").append(new Option(data.please_select, 0));
    $.each(data.models, function(index, item) {
        $("#model_id").append(new Option(index, item));
    });
```

In this case this is exactly what i need but now i need use map cause i am using language file and i have code below

```
Category::find($request->category_id)->orderBy('public_name')->pluck('id', 'public_name')->map(function ($key, $item)  {
    return __('general.' . $item . '');
})
```

but the result is

[image]

I tried modify map func but with no result. Is any way to do this on backend side ? or should i use JS to sort and modify my array ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand your problem correctly. Form what I understand the problem is that you get a collection with arrays `['id', 'public_name']` instead of `['public_name', 'id']`.

You can't manipulate the key with `map` but what you could do is this:

```
Category::find($request->category_id)->orderBy('public_name')->pluck('public_name', 'id')->map(function ($key, $item)  {
    return __('general.' . $key . '');
})->flip();
```

What this does is create a collection of arrays `['id', 'public_name']`, then the `map` replaces the values with the translation and afterwards we `flip` the values and keys so we have `['public_name', 'id']`.